Issue with Algolia Vue InstantSearch: Error with 'searchParameters' option
I'm encountering an issue with configuring Algolia using Vue InstantSearch. Specifically, I'm trying to use the  widget to set search parameters, but I keep receiving the following error:

Error: The 'searchParameters' option expects an object.

I have successfully implemented pagination and basic search functionalities using Algolia Vue InstantSearch. However, when I attempt to configure search parameters using , none of the methods I've tried seem to work.

Using individual props:

<ais-configure
  :hits-per-page.camel="4"
  :distinct="true"
  :enable-personalization.camel="true"
/>


Using search-parameters prop directly:

<ais-configure
  :search-parameters="{
     hitsPerPage: 1
  }"
/>


Attempting to bind an object:

<ais-configure
  :v-bind="{
     hitsPerPage: 1
  }"
/>

Despite these attempts, I consistently receive the error stating that the searchParameters option expects an object. The search and pagination functionalities are working as expected, which suggests that the Algolia integration itself is functional.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to correctly configure <ais-configure> correctly.

A similar issue was reported here.
A pull request has since been merged regarding that issue.
Overall, this was a bug. Now solved in vue-instantsearch@4.16.1, which was released on April 30th, please consider upgrading to at least that version.

Or even v4.17.4 for the latest as of the time of writing this answer.

I updated my version "vue-instantsearch": "^4.17.4" but the issue isn't solved. I tried to load in the component like in the issue you mentioned:
import { AisConfigure } from "vue-instantsearch/vue3/es";
I removed my node_modules and did a clean install.

@dietervanhove do you maybe have a [repro] or a public GitHub repo?

mhh weird, with setting up an example , the problem disapeared:
https://github.com/DieterVanhove/example-algolia/blob/main/example.vue
Don't really know what the issue was...
Thank you for helping

@dietervanhove hehe I am happy that you solved it! Mind dropping an upvote please?
